# Can an ngrx effect dispatch the same action twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an ngrx effect.  From this effect I would like to trigger multiple calls to the same ngrx action but with different parameters.  Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
@Effect({dispatch: true}) 
    public handleNodeWillReceiveFocus$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(nodeWillReceiveFocus),
      concatMap( payload => [
      
        lookuplistShouldRefresh({listname:"billboards"}),
        lookuplistShouldRefresh({listname:"microforms"}),
        
        nodeDidReceiveFocus(payload),
        
      ]),
      
      );
```

The action looks like this:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
export const lookuplistShouldRefresh = createAction(
  '[lookuplists] lookuplistShouldRefresh',
  props<{ listname:string }>()
);
```

The behaviour that I'm observing is that only one of the lookuplistShouldRefresh actions seems to be dispatched (the last one).  If I swap the two calls then I get my "billboards" call.

Both actions result in store mutations.

Is it possible to dispatch the same action multiple times from an effect with different parameters?  I thought that concatMap ran everything in series...?

Update:  I've added some logging and the two actions ARE dispatched correctly but something is amiss elsewhere.

Here is the second effect handler:

```
export class handleLookuplistShouldRefreshEffect {

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private lookuplistAPI: LookuplistAPIService,
      ) {}

      
    @Effect({dispatch: true}) 
    public handleLookupListShouldRefresh$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(lookuplistShouldRefresh),
      tap((payload) => {
        console.log(`EFFECT handleLookupListShouldRefresh has FIRST ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
      }),
      switchMap((payload) => this.lookuplistAPI.getLookupList(payload)),
      tap((payload) => {
        console.log(`EFFECT handleLookuplistShouldRefreshEffect has SECOND ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
      }),
      concatMap( payload => [
        lookuplistDidRefresh({listname:payload["listname"],items:payload["items"]}),
        
      ]),
      
      );

}
```

The API looks like this:

```
export class LookuplistAPIService {

  constructor(private store: Store, private zhttpSvc: ZhttpService) { }

  getLookupList(payload){
    try{
      
      console.log(`getLookupList has payload: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
      const path = this.getPathFromListname(payload.listname);
      
      return this.zhttpSvc.httpGet(path);
       
    }catch(exc){
      console.log(`BANG in getLookupList`);
      return of({});
    }
  }

  getPathFromListname(listname){
    switch(listname){
      case "microforms":
        return "/microform/lookuplist";
        break;
      case "billboards":
        return "/billboard/lookuplist";
        break;
    }
    
  }
}
```

httpGet looks like this:

```
public httpGet(path){
    
    
    const options = {
      withCredentials: true // Allows cookies to be read/set
    };

    
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}${path}`,options);
    
  }
```

"EFFECT handleLookupListShouldRefresh has FIRST..." is logged twice.
"getLookupList has payload..." is logged twice.
"EFFECT handleLookuplistShouldRefreshEffect has SECOND..." is logged ONCE.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong in the way that this code is organised.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I've figured it out.  The issue is in my use of switchMap in handleLookuplistShouldRefreshEffect

switchMap will start handling the first request but will cancel the first request as soon as the second request arrives.  It "switches" to the second emission.

I changed the switchMap to flatMap - flatMap will flatten all emissions into a stream without cancelling any currently running processes.

This explains why I was always getting the LAST request but not the earlier one.